# Can we sync Windows Phone SMS messages on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-8, windows-8.1

I want to know that is there a way to sync or read our `Windows Phone` SMS messages on `Windows 8` via `Windows 8 SDK`.
What I know about Windows Phone is that our SMS messages or chat can be sync to server or on [onedrive](/questions/tagged/onedrive) I think. So I want to fetch all the SMS chat messages on Windows 8 using `Windows 8 SDK`. Is this possible ? if Yes, How? Please Suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible
Windows Phone can't read SMS or Call Logs

Comment: But One day I Format My Phone Completely, and after sometime my text messages synced back from the server. So in that case from where that data came?

Comment: It's automatically done by the OS (when configured) you cannot do that by code

Comment: Thats what I want to say, OS fetching this data automatically from somewhere. So can we implement similar things on Windows?

Comment: Personal SkyDrive(OneDrive now) i think